# Updated spring security context not available in session on redirect

Tags: spring, spring-security

Updated spring security context not available on redirect

In one of my controllers - before redirect - I execute the following code:

```java
Credential oldCredential = (Credential) authentication.getCredentials();
            Authentication authenticationToken = new AuthenticationToken(new Credential(oldCredential.getCookieValue(), oldCredential.getPassword()),
                    updatedAccountDetails);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
```

When I inspect the authentication object after setting it I see the authentication context is correctly updated. After executing the code above I redirect.
After the redirect completes the security context loaded is the old one! That is: when I inspect the security context it contains *not* the new authentication token.

If I do the following for test - I add the  setAttributE(...) after setAuthentication(...) - I get the new authenticationToken in my session but under (obviously) a different key: test. I tried a couple of strategies for the SecurityContextHolder (MODE_THREADLOCAL, MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL, MODE_GLOBAL) although I think the default MODE_THREADLOCAL is suited for my application.

```java
request.getSession(false).setAttribute("test", authenticationToken);
```

The strange thing is that if I debug and check in SecurityContextPersistenceFilter the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository I see that *after* the redirect the loaded context is actually the new one! For some reason - unknown to me at this moment - this load is however at some later point replaced(?) with the old security context.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've called setAuthenticated(true) otherwise the security context is not updated.